# Streamz with websocket not steaming any data

Tags: websocket, streamz

I am to figure out a right way of streaming data using streamz with websocket.

```
ticker_list = ["SCHG"]

# Create DataFrame with specified columns and ticker_list as index
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Bid', 'Ask', 'Time'], index=ticker_list)

source = Stream()

def update_dataframe(json_message, df):
    ticker_data = json_message[0]
    ticker_symbol = ticker_data['S']
    df.loc[ticker_symbol, 'Bid'] = ticker_data['bp']
    df.loc[ticker_symbol, 'Ask'] = ticker_data['ap']
    df.loc[ticker_symbol, 'Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ticker_data['t'], unit='s').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('America/New_York').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

    source.emit(df.copy())  # Emit the updated DataFrame to the stream

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened connection")
    # Authentication
    auth_data = {"action":"auth","key": config.API_KEY,"secret": config.SECRET_KEY}

    # Subscribe
    ws.send(json.dumps(auth_data))
    
    listen_message = {"action":"subscribe","quotes":ticker_list}
    ws.send(json.dumps(listen_message))
    print('subscribed')       

def on_message(ws, message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    
    # Update the DataFrame and emit it to the stream
    update_dataframe(json_message, df)

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

def print_result(x):
    print(x)

sink = source.map(print_result)  # Set up a sink to consume and process the emitted data

socket = "wss://stream.data.alpaca.markets/v2/iex"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

My streaming data is loaded using websocket but not streaming anything. I can print data normally but not working with streamz.